# python multiprocessing pool method is not working

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am setting up a parallel computing pipeline using 50 cores. However, the system is only using 1 core. Here is a test code I am using.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import math

def f(x):
    return math.factorial(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(50) as p:
        print(p.map(f, range(10000)))
```

I saved the code in a script and ran it. However, only one core is used. Any suggestions on what did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? 99% of that code's execution time will be spent doing `print()` (which will be on one thread), not calculating the values. You probably just missed that it engaged 50 cores for a split second.

Answer (score 1):

In order to `print` the `p.map(f, range(10000))` expression, `str` is implicitly called on `p.map(f, range(10000))`.

Calling `str` on such a long list with such large numbers is VERY slow. This is what's taking up all the time. The calculation itself is done almost instantly, so you miss it when looking at the core usage.

Note that `print` is also relatively fast in this case. It's specifically the conversion of the list to a string that's taking up the time here.